# online xml to html parser

Tags: html, xml, parsing

I am looking for a online program that parses any xml to html. For instance, if I have the following xml layout

```
<users>
    <user>
         </name>john</name>
         <pictures>
              <pic1>URL of picture1.png</pic1>
              <pic2>URL of picture2.png</pic2>
         </pictures>
    </user>
    <user>
         </name>mary</name>
         <pictures>
              <pic1>URL of picture1.png</pic1>
              <pic2>URL of picture2.png</pic2>
         </pictures>
    </user>
</users>
```

it can create an html page displaying the content of the nodes and give some minimal formatting for easy reading. Any such tool?

Edit: I just gave an example, I want a generic tool that can parse any xml without knowing its structure beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this would be to apply an XSLT transformation.

You'd need to create an XSL stylesheet, something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="//user">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="name" /></h2>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="pictures/pic1" /></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="pictures/pic2" /></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then link to it at the top of your xml file. In the example below the second line links to the stylesheet named 'myStyleSheet.xsl'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myStyleSheet.xsl"?>
<users>
    <user>
         <name>john</name>
         <pictures>
              <pic1>URL of picture1.png</pic1>
              <pic2>URL of picture2.png</pic2>
         </pictures>
    </user>
    <user>
         <name>mary</name>
         <pictures>
              <pic1>URL of picture1.png</pic1>
              <pic2>URL of picture2.png</pic2>
         </pictures>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: This solution assumes that I know the structure of the xml file.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_choose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Artist</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="price > 10">
     <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
     <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
     </td>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is in no way generic and in case of the example given by the OP the result has nothing to do with the original data.